# Margin is collapsing on removing border

Tags: css

> Scenario

I have created and placed a DIV in bootstrap grid. I am aligning 4 items inside the DIV, viz.

1. Header (Relative, 100% width)
2. Paragraph (Absolute - Bottom Left)
3. Paragraph (Absolute - Bottom Right)
4. Background (Absolute - 100% width, 4rem height, bottom)

[Demo](http://abhi9bakshi.com/code-playground/#col-border-margin-collapse)

> Problem

When I remove the border from DIV (CSS - Line 118), the margin of (1) collapses with margin of (2) and (3), (or that's what it seems like.) What might be the issue?

> Note

I cannot assign fixed height to the DIV because I need the DIV to expand when there is more content in header, as visible in third DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work without `border` but with `display: flex` on ".content" and `width: 100%` on ".title" class. You may also replace `border` by `outline` on ".content-border-js" and ".content-border-css" in order to avoid moving siblings elements when you mouse over one of them.

```
.content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 25rem;
  background-color: white;
  /*border: 1px solid transparent;*/
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #bbb;
  transition: border 100ms ease;
}

.content .title{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 3rem 1rem 8rem;
}

.content-border-js{
  outline: 1px solid #f3df49;
}
.content-border-css{
  oultine: 1px solid #33a9dc;
}
```

**EDIT : WITHOUT FLEXBOX**

ok another solution without flexbox :

set `outline` on ".content-border-js" and ".content-border-css". Then use `overflow: auto` on ".content" class.

```
.content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 25rem;
  background-color: white;
  /*border: 1px solid transparent;*/
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #bbb;
  transition: border 100ms ease;
}

.content-border-js{
  outline: 1px solid #f3df49;
}
.content-border-css{
  oultine: 1px solid #33a9dc;
}
```

Comment: Hey de jaune, thanks for suggesting that. Unfortuntely I cannot use flexbox since I also have to support older browsers. I appreciate your effort very much though :)

Comment: You are welcome ! But I am tenacious, I have another solution for you ;) I edited my answer. Tell me if it's ok for you.

Comment: You... sir... are Awesome !!! :)   I'm marking this as the correct answer. However, if possible, please tell me how adding only overflow fixed this gigantic problem :p     Once again, thanks a bunch.